# Postgres UPSERT reuse column values from INSERT on UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, upsert

I have a basic upsert query that works ok:

```
insert into table (id, data) values (1, '<data_string>') 
    on conflict (id) do update set data='<data_string>';
```

The only problem is I need to fly lots of these queries over the network  so I wonder if there is a way to cut the traffic in half by not having `<data_string>` listed twice in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is the special table `EXCLUDED` for the purpose:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id, data)
VALUES (1, '<data_string>') 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET data = EXCLUDED.data;
```

Like [the manual explains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html):

> Note that the special `excluded` table is used to reference values originally proposed for insertion:

Works for multi-row INSERTs as well:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id, data)
VALUES (1, '<data_string1>') 
     , (2, '<data_string2>') 
     , (3, '<data_string3>') 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET data = EXCLUDED.data;
```