# UPSERT in a WHILE loop fails with invalid column reference

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, upsert, generate-series

I want to run an UPSERT in a `WHILE` loop . This is my query:

```
do $$ declare start_date date := '2021-01-16';
begin 
    while start_date::date < '2021-03-01' loop
    insert
        into
        A ( id,
        "year",
        "month",
        movement,
        status)
        (
        select
            id,
            date_year,
            date_month,
            s_movement,
            move_status
        from
            B
        where
            date_year = extract(year
        from
            start_date::date)
            and date_month = (extract(month
        from
            start_date::date)+ 1)
            and date_day = extract(day
        from
            start_date::date))
       on conflict (id) do 
       update set status = move_status, movement = s_movement;
   start_date:=start_date+interval '1 day';
   end loop;
end $$
```

But when I run this query, it gives error:

> ```
> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "move_status" does not exist Hint:
> There is a column named "move_status" in table "*SELECT*", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
> ```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause for the error is that you are trying to reference input column names, but only target column names are visible in the `UPDATE` part of the UPSERT. And you have to table-qualify those with the [virtual table name `EXCLUDED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT).

But there is more. Use a set-based solution based on `generate_series()` instead of the loop in a `DO` command. Much more efficient:

```sql
INSERT INTO A
      (id, year     , month     , movement  , status)
SELECT id, date_year, date_month, s_movement, move_status
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2021-01-16'
                     , timestamp '2021-02-28'
                     , interval '1 day')  start_date
JOIN   B ON date_year  = extract(year  FROM start_date)
        AND date_month = extract(month FROM start_date) + 1
        AND date_day   = extract(day   FROM start_date)
ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET    status   = EXCLUDED.status                     -- here!
     , movement = EXCLUDED.movement;                  -- and here!
```

Aside: Consider a single column of type `date` to replace the three columns `date_year`, `date_month`, `date_day`. Much cleaner and more efficient.

Further reading:

- [Postgres UPSERT reuse column values from INSERT on UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673288/postgres-upsert-reuse-column-values-from-insert-on-update/52673556#52673556)
- [Ambiguous column reference in INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202402/ambiguous-column-reference-in-insert-on-conflict-do-update/66203037#66203037)
- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)